# Build failed in Jenkins: Eigen Dependency in Indigo

Tags: eigen, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to release a **ROS Indigo** version of a package, but I got an email back saying that "the build failed in Jenkins". This seems to be the error:

```
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen" with any of
  the following names:

    EigenConfig.cmake
    eigen-config.cmake
```

However, the package's *package.xml* has both a build and a run dependency on *cmake_modules*, and the *CMakeLists* file contains:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS cmake_modules [...])

find_package(Eigen REQUIRED)
```

**UPDATE**

According to the answer below, I've updated the **CMakeLists.txt**: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/atenpas/handle_detector/indigo/CMakeLists.txt

However, Jenkins is still failing with the same error message as before.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/207881/build-failed-in-jenkins:-eigen-dependency-in-indigo/) by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 529 on 2015-04-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try the following please:

```
find_package(catkin REQUIRED cmake_modules )
find_package(Eigen REQUIRED)
```

where cmake_modules is not a component

Maybe a stupid question: did you install Eigen on your board?

---

Originally posted by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) with karma: 893 on 2015-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on 2015-04-25**:
Interesting. I have another project that was released successfully in **ROS Indigo** which uses `catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS cmake_modules` ...

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2015-04-25**:
Fixed now?

**Comment by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on 2015-04-25**:
I fixed it in the CMakeLists file. I only know whether it helped when I get the next email from Jenkins.

**Comment by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on 2015-04-26**:
Do I have to make a new release? I pushed the changes onto the repository's branch, but they don't seem to be in Jenkins build from last night ...

**Comment by [atp](https://answers.ros.org/users/5347/atp/) on 2015-04-27**:
Actually, to be more precise: is it possible to see what code is trying to be compiled in Jenkins?